# sum string values from vector of maps clojure

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I have a vector of maps, something like below although there are up to possbly 100 maps in each dataset:

```
data({ a:a b:"2" c:t}{ a:b b:"0" c:t}{ a:c b:"-4" c:t}{ a:d b:"100" c:t}{ a:e b:"50" c:t})
```

I need to produce the sum of :b

```
values(map :b data)
sum(reduce + (map read-string values)
```

This gives the desired result but the calcuation is taking to long, about 1/10 a second.  I am doing this for several hundred thousand datasets so it is taking up a lot of the processing time to do this.

Can anyone suggest a more efficent/faster way to this approach?

Thanks

Comment: Please give real clojure code instead of this pseude-code. We can take it.

Comment: that is real clojure code...

Comment: Why not store int as int rather than string? Performance doesnt come only from algorithm, it is combination of structure + algorithm

Comment: @redhands, No it's not! I tried it and I got a bunch of errors. Seriously, though, you'd better provide important information in your question. Like the fact, that you're using older version of clojure (which one?).

Comment: @Ankur, thanks I tried parsing the source data and then running the calculation but still no real improvement to performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use [reducers](http://clojure.org/reducers) which run in parallel:

```
(require '[clojure.core.reducers :as r])
(r/reduce + (r/map read-string values))
```

For your small testcase this will not improve runtime, but for large datasets it should.

Comment: Would love to use reducers but unfortunately I am using an older version of clojure and wont be able to upgrade anytime soon

Comment: You can get some of the parallelism by using `pmap`. It was available from clojure 1.0 so you should be able use it.

Answer (score 5):

Here's 1/10th of your total 100.000 dataset scenario done in slightly over 1/10th of a second, on Clojure 1.2.1. It's basically your code (which isn't really valid clojure syntax, but we get the gist), but somehow runs 10.000x as fast.

```
;generate 10.000 datasets of 100 maps having 10 fields each

(def scenario-data
    (vec (repeatedly 10000
                     (fn [] (vec (repeatedly 100 (fn [] (zipmap
                                                            [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j]
                                                            (repeatedly (fn [] (str (- (rand-int 2000) 1000))))))))))))


;now map the datasets into the reduced sums of the parsed :b fields of each dataset

(time (doall (map (fn [dataset] (reduce (fn [acc mp] (+ acc (Integer/parseInt (:b mp)))) 0 dataset))
                  scenario-data)))
"Elapsed time: 120.43267 msecs"
=> (2248 -6383 7890 ...)
```

Since this scenario is pretty memory intensive (*10.000 datasets ~=600MB, total calculation uses ~4GB*), I can't run the 100.000 dataset scenario on my home machine. However, I can run it if I don't keep the datasets in memory, but map over a lazy sequence without holding on to it's head..

```
(time (doall (map (fn [dataset] (reduce (fn [acc mp] (+ acc (Integer/parseInt (:b mp)))) 0 dataset))
                  (repeatedly 100000
                              (fn [] (repeatedly 100 (fn [] (zipmap
                                                              [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j]
                                                              (repeatedly (fn [] (str (- (rand-int 2000) 1000))))))))))))
"Elapsed time: 30242.371308 msecs"
=> (-4975 -843 1560 ...)
```

That's 30 seconds for calculating your 100.000 dataset version, and *includes all the time needed for generating the data*. Using `pmap` cuts that time roughly in half (4 cores).

*Edit*: Creating a fully realized 100.000 datasets on a machine with enough memory takes 135 s. Running the summation code over it takes ~1500 msecs. Using `pmap` cuts this down to ~750 msecs. A `read-string` version is ~3.5x slower.

**TL/DR: the algorithm you posted can be run on a 100.000 dataset scenario within 1 sec, given enough memory.**

Please post your complete code, including how you read and keep the datasets in memory, and make sure both syntax and observations are accurate this time. It probably is more of a memory problem from not reading the datasets lazily from the source.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `Integer/parseInt` or `Long/parseLong` instead of the more general `read-string`.

[EDIT]

A simple test with Clojure 1.5.1 shows that parseInt is about 10 times faster:

```
user=> (time (dotimes [n 100000] (read-string "10")))
"Elapsed time: 142.516849 msecs"
nil

user=> (time (dotimes [n 100000] (Integer/parseInt "10")))
"Elapsed time: 12.754187 msecs"
nil
```

Comment: I had tried that (reduce + (map#(Integer/parseint %1) values)) but it makes no difference